# Strange behavior with \draw within axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \draw[-latex,cyan] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1,1);
    \addplot coordinates {(1,1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `\draw` doesn't show up if I comment out the `\addplot`. Something I've missed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your log file will contain the message

```
Package pgfplots Warning: You have an axis with empty range (in direction y). Replacing it with a default range and clearing all plots. on input line 8.
```

The cure would be to add `xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax` with appropriate values.

Comment: I need start reading the logs, this isn't part of my workflow with LaTeX. No one I know can produce zero warning code.